# Duda básica con margin. Padre e hijo css

Tags: html, css, css3, margin

Sé como solucionarlo, pero mi duda va en el por qué pasa esto. Tengo un section Padre y dentro un div Hijo. La cosa es que al colocar margin:20px en el hijo, Se le aplica un margin a todo, no solo al hijo que es donde yo quería aplicarlo respecto al padre. Porque se le aplica a todo? Se que se soluciona colocando un position: absolute al padre. Pero sin esto, porque se le aplica a todo mi contenido, padre e hijo. ¿Tiene alguna explicación?

```css
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#padre{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
}

#hijo  {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <section id="padre">

  <div id="hijo" >1</div>

 </section>

</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La explicación es que esto se llama "márgenes colapsadas".

> Las márgenes verticales (superior -top- e inferior -bottom-) de los elementos bloque (block) se colapsan o combinan en ciertas ocasiones, y predomina la margen más grande, o alguna de ellas, en caso que sean iguales.

Esto ocurre en tres casos principalmente:

- **Hermanos adyacentes:**
  Los márgenes de los hermanos adjacentes son colapsados (excepto cuando el último hermano necesita ser limpiado luego de los flotantes).
- **Padre y primer/último hijo:** Si no hay un borde, padding, contenido en línea, o limpiado para separar el margin-top de un bloque del margin-top de su primer bloque hijo, o no hay borde, padding, contenido en línea, height, min-height, o max-height para separar el margin-bottom de un bloque del margin-bottom de su último hijo, entonces esos márgenes colapsan. El margen colapsado termina fuera del padre.
- **Bloques vacíos:** Si no hay borde, padding, contenido en línea, height, o min-height para separar el margin-top de un bloque de su margin-bottom, entonces sus márgenes superiores e inferiores colapsan.

---

Como podemos ver, en el ejemplo que expones aplica el segundo caso "Padre y primer/útimo hijo". Apliqué un borde transparente de 1px para demostrar lo que dice la documentación: *"Si no hay borde o ... que separe el margin-top padre del margin-top hijo, ..."*, entonces al agregar el borde, básicamente no se colapsan.

```css
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#padre{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
  border-top: solid 1px transparent;
}

#hijo  {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="padre">

  <div id="hijo" >1</div>

 </section>
```

---

Referencias:

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing