# Problema al dar margenes a elementos del dom

Tags: css, html5

Mi computadora esta haciendo lo que quiere.

Tengo dos divs:

```css
.div_producto {
  background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.7);
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 380px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_producto">
  <div style="background-color: #ff0000; margin-top: 140px; width: 140px;">Este es un texto</div>
</div>
```

Cuando le doy margen superior al `div hijo` me mueve el `div padre` y cuando trato de centrar el `div hijo` por ejemplo: `margin: 4px auto;` solo me centra en relación a **x** y **y** no lo respeta puesto que me lo deja pegado al borde superior del padre.

Por que esta haciendo eso??

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Duda basica con margin. Padre e hijo css](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155171/duda-basica-con-margin-padre-e-hijo-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El *"problema"* se debe al [colapso de margen](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Modelo_Caja/Mastering_margin_collapsing) (`margin collapsing`)

### Solución:

Agregar al padre `overflow: auto;`

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.div_producto {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.7);
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 380px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_producto">
  <div style="background-color: #ff0000; margin-top: 140px; width: 140px;">Este es un texto</div>
</div>
```